# UnitTesting questions to check my coding

Tags: python

My assignment is to test my Statslist for reasonable inputs that might go into using my StatsList class. I'm very confused on how to make unittests for these questions provided. I've correctly done the first one in class. The questions are:

1. What is the count, mean, median, and mode of an empty list (a StatsList that nothing's been appended to)?
2. What is the count, mean, median, and mode of a list with one value?
3. What is the count, mean, median, and mode of a list with two values?
4. If values are inserted in the wrong order (as in the example above), does the median still work?
5. If values are inserted in order, does the median still work?
6. If there are multiple values that all appear the same number of times, what will the mode be?

Coding:
    import unittest
    import statslist

```
class StatsTest(unittest.TestCase):
     def test_Append(self):
        sl = statslist.StatsList()

        self.assertEqual(0, sl.count())
        sl.append(10)
        self.assertEqual(1, sl.count())

    def test_OneValue(self):



    def test_Mean(self):
        self.assert

    def test_Median(self):


    def test_Mode(self):



if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Coding for StatsList:

```
  class StatsList:
        def __init__(self):
        self.sum = 0
        self.nums = []

    def append(self, number):
        self.nums.append(number)

    def count(self):
        count = len(self.nums)
        return count

    def mean(self):
        for num in self.nums:
            self.sum = self.sum + num

        return self.sum /len(self.nums)

    def median(self):
        self.nums.sort()
        midPos = self.count() // 2

        if self.count() % 2 == 0:
            median = (nums[midPos] + nums[midPos-1]) / 2.0
        else:
            median = self.nums[midPos]

        return median

    def mode(self):
        counts= {}
        for num in self.nums:
           counts[num] = counts.get(num,0) + 1
           mode = max(counts, key = counts.get)

        return mode  

def byFreq(pair):
    return pair[1]

def main():
    l = StatsList()
    l.append(1)
    l.append(11)
    l.append(3)
    l.append(1)
    l.append(4)

    print("Count:", l.count()) # should print 5
    print("Mean:", l.mean()) # should print 4.0
    print("Median:", l.median()) # should print 3
    print("Mode:", l.mode()) # should print 1


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can write something like this:

```
import unittest
import statslist

class StatsTest(unittest.TestCase):
     def test_append(self):
        sl = statslist.StatsList()

        self.assertEqual(0, sl.count())
        sl.append(10)
        self.assertEqual(1, sl.count())

    def test_one_value(self):
        # given
        sl = statslist.StatsList()

        # when
        sl.append(10)

        # then
        self.assertEqual(1, sl.count())
        self.assertEqual(10, sl.mean())
        self.assertEqual(10, sl.median())
        self.assertEqual(10, sl.mode())

    def test_two_values(self):
        # given
        sl = statslist.StatsList()

        # when
        sl.append(10)
        sl.append(11)

        # then
        self.assertEqual(1, sl.count())
        self.assertEqual(10, sl.mean())
        self.assertEqual(10, sl.median())
        self.assertEqual(10, sl.mode())

    def test_median_wrong_order(self):
        # given
        sl = statslist.StatsList()

        # when
        sl.append(12)
        sl.append(13)
        sl.append(11)

        # then
        self.assertEqual(12, sl.median())

    def test_median_in_order(self):
        # given
        sl = statslist.StatsList()

        # when
        sl.append(11)
        sl.append(12)
        sl.append(13)

        # then
        self.assertEqual(12, sl.median())

    def test_mode_with_multiple_vals_same_num_of_times(self):
        # given
        sl = statslist.StatsList()

        # when
        sl.append(11)
        sl.append(11)
        sl.append(12)
        sl.append(12)
        sl.append(13)

        # then
        self.assertEqual(11, sl.mode())
```

The idea of unit tests is to make sure your code actually works the way it is supposed to. It is a great way to discover bugs early and to prevent you having to spend countless hours debugging that weird bug that's just happened in production.

Your unit test should cover all (or most) edge cases. This brings an additional advantage: it automatically documents your code and helps others refactor your code later because they can just run the unit tests and if there is an error after refactoring, that probably means they've done something wrong.

Depending on your needs, you could improve your code to automatically track the stats when an element is added. This would make the `mean()`, `median()`, `count()` and `mode()` execute with `O(1)` complexity, however depending on the algorithms used it might slow down the `append()` method.